# Next.js 13 global context using layout.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, state, react-context

I am trying to use Next.js to create a web app with authentication and global user state. Once a user is signed in I would like to display the user in the navbar, and also share that user state with the child components which may make API calls that require the user information. I am using Next.js 13 with the `app` directory and the `app/layout.js` file to store my navbar and user state.

My issue is that the navbar in `app/layout.js` is able to consistently display the username once it is decoded from the JSON web token, however this is not displayed within my child component (`app/loginsuccess/page.jsx`) which needs to have the user state too.

`context/MyContext.js`

```js
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const MyContext = createContext({
  value: null, 
  setValue: () => {}, 
});

export const MyProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null); 
  
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ value, setValue }}>
      {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default MyContext;
```

`app/layout.jsx`

```js
"use client";

import "./globals.css";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import { MyProvider } from "@/context/MyContext";

const getUserFromJWTCookie = async () => {
  const authToken = Cookies.get("token");
  const response = await fetch("/api/session", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ token: authToken }),
  });
  const responseData = await response.json();
  const username = responseData.username;
  if (username) {
    console.log("getUserFromJWTCookie", username);
    return username;
  }
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const user = await getUserFromJWTCookie();
      setUser(user);
      if (!user) {
        router.replace("/logintest");
      }
    })();
  }, [router]);

  return (
    <MyProvider value={{ value: user, setValue: setUser }}>
      <html lang="en">
        <body>
          <nav className="bg-gray-800 text-white p-4">
            <ul className="flex justify-center space-x-4">
              <li className="hover:bg-gray-700 rounded-md p-2">
                <Link href="/show">
                  <h1 className="text-xl font-semibold">Shows</h1>
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="hover:bg-gray-700 rounded-md p-2">
                <Link href="/user">
                  <h1 className="text-xl font-semibold">Users</h1>
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="hover:bg-gray-700 rounded-md p-2">
                <Link href="/loginsuccess">
                  <h1 className="text-xl font-semibold">{user}</h1>
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <main>{children}</main>
        </body>
      </html>
    </MyProvider>
  );
}
```

`app/loginsuccess/page.jsx`

```js
"use client";

import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MyContext from "@/context/MyContext";

const ProtectedPage = () => {
  const { value } = useContext(MyContext);
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(value);
  }, [value]);

  return <div>Welcome! {user}</div>;
};

export default ProtectedPage;
```

Any help in making this render at the same time in my child component is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you try adding a `console.log(value)` in `context/MyContext.js` just before you return the provider, and then another one right after the `useContext(MyContext)` in `app/loginsuccess/page.jsx`?  Either `value` is never being set correctly in the provider (in which case the 1st log will show it), `value` isn't being passed correctly through context (eg. `ProtectedPage` isn't inside the provider ... in which case the 2nd log will show it) ... and if both logs look normal then that means the problem is in the page.

Comment: I created both of these `console.log` statements but neither of them return a value that isn't `null`. The only `console.log` that returns the username is the one in my `getUserFromJWTCookie` function in the `app/layout.js` file. This must mean that `value` is not being set correctly in the provider...

Comment: I'd try adding a `console.log(user, 'user')` after `const user = await getUserFromJWTCookie();` , and also change the one inside the `if (username) {` to come just before it instead (so you see it every time the function runs).  I'm curious to see if `getUserFromJWTCookie`  is running multiple times or just once, and also what the `user` state variable is being set to.

Comment: I have updated the `console.log`s as you have said. I can confirm that the `console.log` inside `getUserFromJWTCookie` is just running once and it does appear to log the correct username. I have changed the variable name for less confusion & I added a `console.log` after the line `const JWTuser = await getUserFromJWTCookie();` and it does return the value too. I also added a `console.log(user)` (which is the `setUser` value) before and after the line `setUser(JWTuser)`, neither of which return a value which means my `setUser` isn't working.

Comment: `setUser` definitely works; state is core to React. Does your code really look like what you have there, specifically `if (!user) {` part?  Because as written, that's using the local variable `user`, not the `user` state variable ... which should be what you want as the local var will have the result of your function call.  However, if your code is different (eg. if you named `user` something else) you might be misunderstanding how state works.

Comment: If I do `const [foo, setFoo]  = useState(0);`, then I do `console.log(foo); setFoo(2); console.log(foo);`, what do you think it will log?  `0` and then `2`, right?  Wrong: it will log `0`, `0`, because state-setters are asynchronous.  They *don't* change the state variable until the next render happens (ie. until the function is called again).  Could this explain things?

Answer (score 1):

Since there was no reply to my comment, I'll assume it guessed correctly.

Your displayed code includes the following:

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const user = await getUserFromJWTCookie();
      setUser(user);
      if (!user) {
        router.replace("/logintest");
      }
    })();
  }, [router]);
```

In that code you have two different variables called `user`: the state variable, and the local one (set to the result of `getUserFromJWTCookie`).  That code will work fine, because the second (non-state) variable masks the state variable.

However, if your code was more interesting (perhaps you only shared a simplified example?), that approach could cause a problem.  For instance, if you used a different variable name:

```
      const userFromServer = await getUserFromJWTCookie();
      setUser(userFromServer);
      if (!user) {
```

the code would break.  Why?  Because when you `setUser(userFromServer);` it **does not** change the `user` variable ... until the next render (ie. until the function is called again).

This is how state works in React: when you call a setState function, it only changes the variable "behind the scenes"; for the rest of the function, the variable maintains its old value.

As a side note, React does this because of the limits of Javascript.  In JS there's no way to do:

```
 let x = 5;
 doSomething(x);
 // x = 6 (doesn't work)
```

Functions can only change primitive variables within their own scope, not outside of it.  Now, if the variable is an object, you **can** "mutate" it:

```
let x = {};
doSomething(x);
// x.a = 6 (works)
```

... but since state variables could be objects or primitives, it has to work for both ... and that means React's setState function can't change the original state variable.

Comment: Your answer has helped me understand React better, and I understand that I have been doing this wrong, however, I am not sure the correct way to fix my issue of things not rendering until the next render. Do I need to render everything twice?

Comment: Sort of: React work by *reacting* to state changes by rendering fresh UI, so your user can make more changes (see https://www.exploringreact.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/unidirectional.png).  Typically you load the page: React renders #1.  Then you change a state variable in an event handler: for the rest of that event handler's call, your state variable will have its old value.  But, once the handler is done, React will see the state change and re-render.  Now, when it runs your render function again, the state variable will have the new value, so you'll see it once that render finishes.

Comment: If you aren't seeing a change in your UI, it either means the state-setting didn't work (eg. you wrapped it in an `if` that's not triggering), or it did work, but some other code isn't using that state variable.  But again, the moment you change any state (via a `setFoo(true)` function) React will re-render (re-run your function, and update the DOM with what it returns) a few milliseconds later.  If you add a `console.log` you should see the new state value in your component's function on this (second) render.

Comment: P.S. And `useEffect` is for handling stuff that you *don't* want to happen as part of  this cycle.  Imagine you fetch a list of options for your component (because it renders a `<select>`): if you put that in your component function, it will re-fetch *every time you re-render* (ie. whenever you change state).  To avoid that, you can put the `fetch` inside a `useEffect(() => fetch(url).then(something), [])`.  The `[]` says "never re-run this useEffect".  If you had say `[abc]` then it would re-run the `useEffect`, but still not every render: only when `abc` changes.

Comment: One last thought: whenever you do `setValue(newValue)`, `value` will remain the old/wrong value for the rest of that function ... but `newValue` will still be the new/correct value.  In that function you just want to use `newValue`, not `value` (but again, later on in a future re-render of your component, `value` *will* be the `newValue`, so you can just use `value` there).